# sqlite TEXT column name same as value bug

Tags: android, sqlite

I have found what appears to be a strange bug with sqlite.

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE controller(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, controller_number TEXT, password TEXT);
```

With data

```
INSERT INTO controller (controller_number, password) VALUES ("1234", 1234);
```

No problems there, but check this out.

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM controller; 
1|1234|1234
sqlite> UPDATE controller SET controller_number="12345", password="password" WHERE id=1;
sqlite>  SELECT * FROM controller;
1|12345|1234
```

can anyone explain why this is happening, or this a bug that should be raised?

Comment: did it work w/the single quote?

Comment: I agree with Sid and my testing shows that the issue is with mis-using quotes in the SQLite language specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>CREATE TABLE controller(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, controller_number TEXT, password TEXT);
>INSERT INTO controller (controller_number, password) VALUES ("1234", 1234);
>SELECT * FROM controller; 
1|1234|1234
>UPDATE controller SET controller_number="12345", password="password" WHERE id=1;
>SELECT * FROM controller;
1|12345|1234
```

Above causes an issue, but if do this

```
>UPDATE controller SET controller_number='123456', password='password' WHERE id=1;
```

I get this

```
>SELECT * FROM controller;
1|123456|password
```

It is clear what is going on, the first UPDATE was setting password=password rather then password="password" and second query executes the correct way.

Can anyone elaborate on why this happens, or should it happen in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

It may be the double quotes:

> 'keyword'     A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
>   "keyword"     A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.

from http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: I dont think i do. The INSERT is not the problem. As you should be able to see from the above code, the INSERT adds a row to table fine. The UPDATE only updates the the controller_number column and leaves the password column unchanged. It would appear that the query has been run on the database and has not returned an error. However a SELECT statement reveals that the query actually failed to UPDATE the password column. This is only an issue when the value of the password column matched the column name.

Comment: so if you change the column value to something else it works fine?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. "UPDATE controller SET controller_number="12345", password="54321" WHERE id=1;" Works and both fields get updated. I have tested it with other field names and the problem seems to be TEXT fields where the value is the same as the column name. E.G. UPDATE controller SET controller_number="controller_number", password="54321"; results in 1|07725686891|54321

Comment: can you try using a single quote?

Answer (score 0):

For any field value that is the same as any field name in a SELECT or UPDATE statement, you must use single quotes (meaning a literal value, not double quotes, which means a field name) for that field value. I fixed this in my app.